# App not visible when share content from Apple news and Safari

Tags: ios, xcode8, ios8-share-extension

We are using Mac OS 13.6.1, Xcode Version 14.2 (14C18). We have created a new target in the project for "Share Extension". After running the code our app is not visible when we share content from Apple News and Safari. Please do let me know if anyone needs more information. I really appreciate any help you can provide.